# Can VS break at an error in a DLL I have source code for?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I am developing a C# Console app with Visual Studio 2013 Pro targeting .NET 4.0.
Part of this project includes confidential IP so I have created a DLL which contains that IP and a dummy DLL which I use when I have to hand out the code to other folks. I use a `#if` to include one or the other.   The stub compiles and provides testing capabilities.   The DLL Actually started out as just another class of the Console app but I just compile it separately to a DLL now.  .NET4.0.

**I can set breakpoints either in my Main or my DLL and it works fine.** I can step through both etc.
**The issue is that if there is an error in the DLL, VS breaks at the call in the main program and not at the error in the DLL with a not-so-helpful error message.**  I then have to guess where in the DLL to set a breakpoint.

Previous posts suggest I ensure that my compile options are set to Debug (they are) and that the .pdb file for me DLL are in the references folder of the main program.   I don’t know what the reference folder is but the DLL .pdb  is in the bin/x64/Debug folder.

The DLL is part of my Solution. In other words, the Solution Explorer for my main Console app allows me to open the DLL source code and set a breakpoint.   The only pain in the part is that I have to "rebuild" the dll each time I run or the main program won't see the changes.

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
-Ed

Comment: Usuallly this means the debugger doesn't find the PDB file. When debugging, open the 'Modules" windows in VS, check the if PDB file of the DLL is loaded or not.

Comment: The .dll shows up in the Module window when debugging.  But it does say that the SYMBOLS ARE LOADED and the file path is to the PDB.  So it sounds like it is loaded... and like I said, I "can" breakpoint and step thru the code of the dll.  The only issue if that if something fails, it does not 'break' in the code but at the main program's calling function.